# Help with rearranging equation to get real and imaginary parts..

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I know this is so simple but my algebra is totally failing me..  I have the equation 1/1+2i and I want to extract the real and imaginary parts so I have it in the form..

Re+Im  could someone just show me the algebra steps for doing this please..  Thanks

Comment: $\dfrac{1}{1+2i} = \dfrac{1-2i}{(1+2i)(1-2i)} = \ldots$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiply by the conjugate:
$$
\frac{1}{1+2i}=\frac{1}{1+2i}\cdot \frac{1-2i}{1-2i}=\frac{1-2i}{5}.
$$

Comment: Being a non-native speaker: shouldn't it be called “expand with” instead of “multiply by”?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe  I use "multiply" because I am multiplying two complex numbers together.

Comment: But you didn't multiply by the conjugate but with $1$ instead ... Just nitpicking

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I multiplied by the conjugate twice, once on top and once on bottom.  So, I did multiply by the conjugate.

Comment: OK, but what is the proper verb for “to multiply the nominator and the denominator of a fraction by the same number“?  It's called “erweitern” in german and I presumed that the english verb is “to expand by.”  In case you multiply a fraction by a number you'll multiply the nominator of the fraction by this number and leave the denominator unchanged.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe  As with "doch", there is no good English equivalent.  One would just say "multiply top and bottom by" or "multiply the numerator and denominator by".

Comment: Thankyou so much for this answer it is just so clear.. I have found that my algebra really sucks when it comes to this kind of stuff.. Like I know that conjugates exist but I really struggle to see the problem and go "ahh this could be solved by multiplying by the conjugate"